# Visualize Polygon Changes

Tags: arcgis-desktop, polygon, editing, versioning, tracking

I've unfortunately experienced a version control issue between offices where one person was editing an older version of a polygon shapefile. Now I need to reconcile those edits into the current version. I've noticed that ESRI has a great tool for identifying polyline changes between shapefiles with the Detect Features Changes tool. However, it doesn't appear that a similar tool exists for polygons.

Any suggests for how I can quickly identify which polygons have been edited? Keep in mind, there are over a thousand polygons. And no, I am not on an enterprise GIS with versioning.

Comment: You are asking for a ESRI tool or for what GIS software?

Comment: ESRI, if possible. I rarely use QGIS these days. I realize there may not be a simple solution for this.

Comment: That could very well do the job. I'll give it a try soon. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

If the changes are not too extensive, the [Symmetrical Difference](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/latest/tools/analysis-toolbox/symmetrical-difference.htm) tool can help you quickly identify differences. The results are polygons representing areas covered by one shapefile or the other, but not both.

Comment: That works beautifully for my situation. Thank you!